Python processes do not have internet access inside the docker
Python processes (not counting the main one) do not have internet access inside the docker.
I have a class BotManager that starts a new Process for each AsyncTelebot. It has methods:
    async def add_bot(self, api_key: str):
        if api_key not in self.bots:
            if await self._check_bot(api_key):
                bot = AsyncTeleBot(api_key)
                self.bots[api_key] = bot

                terminate_flag = multiprocessing.Event()
                self.terminate_flags[api_key] = terminate_flag

                process = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.bot_polling_process,
                                                  args=(api_key, terminate_flag),
                                                  daemon=True)
                self.processes[api_key] = process
                process.start()
            else:
                raise InvalidBotKeyException('Неверный API ключ для бота')
        else:
            raise BotAlreadyWorksException('Такой бот уже работает')

    @staticmethod
    def bot_polling_process(api_key, terminate_flag):
        bot = AsyncTeleBot(api_key)
        setup_handlers(bot)

        async def polling():
            while not terminate_flag.is_set():
                try:
                    await bot.infinity_polling(timeout=10, request_timeout=90, interval=0)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Exception occurred: {e}")
                    continue

        asyncio.run(polling())

If i launch app on my PC it works correctly, but when i try to launch it on my server, i get this trace:
2024-07-29 17:17:32,856 (asyncio_helper.py:103 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Unknown error: RuntimeError"
backend     | 2024-07-29 17:17:32,857 (async_telebot.py:370 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Infinity polling exception: Request timeout. Request: method=get url=getMe params=<aiohttp.formdata.FormData object at 0x7fa295e432b0> files=None request_timeout=300"
backend     | 2024-07-29 17:17:32,859 (async_telebot.py:372 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Exception traceback:
backend     | Traceback (most recent call last):
backend     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/async_telebot.py", line 366, in infinity_polling
backend     |     await self._process_polling(non_stop=True, timeout=timeout, request_timeout=request_timeout,
backend     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/async_telebot.py", line 423, in _process_polling
backend     |     self._user = await self.get_me()
backend     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/async_telebot.py", line 2579, in get_me
backend     |     result = await asyncio_helper.get_me(self.token)
backend     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/asyncio_helper.py", line 154, in get_me
backend     |     return await _process_request(token, method_url)
backend     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/asyncio_helper.py", line 105, in _process_request
backend     |     raise RequestTimeout("Request timeout. Request: method={0} url={1} params={2} files={3} request_timeout={4}".format(method, url, params, files, request_timeout, current_try))
backend     | telebot.asyncio_helper.RequestTimeout: Request timeout. Request: method=get url=getMe params=<aiohttp.formdata.FormData object at 0x7fa295e432b0> files=None request_timeout=300
backend     | "

I checked and realized that all python processes (not counting the main one) do not have internet connection
My Dockerfile
FROM python:3.10-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]

docker-compose file:
version: '3.8'

networks:
  dev:

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=telegram_posts
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db
    networks:
      - dev


  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - dev


  backend:
    build:
      context: ./telePosting
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: backend
    environment:
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017
      - MONGO_DB_NAME=telegram_posts
      - REDIS_URL=redis
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - redis
    networks:
      - dev

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./telePostFrontend/vite-project
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: frontend
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
    depends_on:
      - backend
    networks:
      - dev

volumes:
  mongo-data:

How can I fix that problem?
I tried to ping some sites and realized that other processes have no internet connection

I'm 100% sure that your interpretation, i.e. your initial sentence, is wrong. Please extract a [mcve] to further drill down on the core issue. As it stands, there are lots of things that aren't relevant and yet it's still not a complete picture. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

You've created a new network dev in your docker-compose file and assigned it to all your containers.  It has no route to the internet, so those containers will only be able to talk to each other.
If you're not familiar with docker networking, I'd suggest not creating a new network, and just using the default.  Do this by deleting all the networks: sections from your docker-compose.
You can find documentation here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
Alternatively, if you need a network configuration which the default doesn't give you, then you can specify a networks driver: https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/

Firstly I didn't use network. And it didn't work(

The dev network that the question creates should behave pretty much identically to the default network, except it has a different name.  (I'd also recommend deleting it.)
